# $f^n(x)$ where $n \in \mathbb{R}^+$

Tags: analysis

Given a function $f(x)$ whose image is a subset of its domain, we can define
$$
f^n(x) = \underbrace{f(f(f(\dots f(x) \dots )))}_{n \text{ times}}
$$

This makes sense when $n$ is a nonnegative integer.

Can we extend this definition to continuous values of $n$? Such as $f^{\frac{1}{2}}(x)$?

Comment: Maybe, $f^{1/2}$ is defined so that $f^{1/2}\circ f^{1/2}=f$. However, this definition is not good, because in general $f^{1/2}$ is not the only such function (why?).

Comment: It turns out it's called a fractional iterated function!

Comment: Consult the posts here with the tag `(fractional-iteration)` then tell us why this one should not be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x)=x$. You would want $f^{1/2}$ defined so that $$\left(f^{1/2}\circ f^{1/2}\right)(x)=f(x)=x$$

Here are five options, for starters:

- $f^{1/2}(x)=x$
- $f^{1/2}(x)=-x$
- $f^{1/2}(x)=\sqrt[3]{1-x^3}$
- [The implicit solution to

  $x+f^{1/2}(x)=e^{-\left(x-f^{1/2}(x)\right)^2}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+for+y%3A+x%2By%3Dexp%28-%28x-y%29%5E2%29)
- [The implicit solution to

  $x+f^{1/2}(x)=\frac12\cos\mathopen{}\left(x-f^{1/2}(x)\right)\mathclose{}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+for+y%3A+x%2By%3D1%2F2+cos%28x-y%29)

What would be the basis to choose one of these? I could understand a preference for the first option here. But with general $f$, if this is evidence that there are many possibilities for $f^{1/2}$, you might want to have a definition that somehow picks one canonically.

Or maybe you just let $f^{1/2}$ stand for the class of *all* functions that meet the condition $f^{1/2}\circ f^{1/2}=f$.

Answer (score -2):

You see here $n$ is a whole number. If you take it as 0.5 then problems will arise. For example is $n=2$ then that means we input function into itself two times but what $n=0.5$ would mean. Would it mean that we only input half of f or the first term of f or the last term.This becomes ridiculous when n goes out of range

Comment: OP knows this, the question is if there is a natural *extension*. A similar example: what is $1/2$ order derivative of a function. This makes no sense with the usual definition, however in this case there are a meaningful extensions (see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus)

Comment: Also [Iterated function#Fractional iterates and flows, and negative iterates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function#Fractional_iterates_and_flows,_and_negative_iterates) or [Functional square root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_square_root).